# Transfering UV Maps/Custom Normals to identical object

Tags: cycles-render-engine, uv, normals, vector-mapping

Not my model, it's just a custom job and this got me nuts.
I've been almost 5 hours trying to deal with this, I swear this was my last option to solve this problem.

I've got one object with perfect UV map but without Custom Normals.

And another identical object (same verts and faces) with perfect Custom Normals but without UV map

The task looks simple: just copy/paste/transfer the UV Map or the Custom Normals to the other object to make the perfect model.

But it looks impossible, at least by my knowledgement

What I've tried:

- Ctrl + L > transfer UV maps
- Tools > Data transfer UV/Normals
- Magic UV > Copy/Paste UV
- Magic UV > Transfer UV
- Data Transfer modifier

None of them worked, the most close result was using Magic UV but didn't worked.

I'm using Cycles engine and Blender v2.79

Please help me! I really appreciate your time and efforts!

[image]

**UPDATE**

LukeD's answer is ok, but still having issues at the transferred UV map to the other model, look at this attachments:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Transfer UV Maps** is working just fine.

1. Select object with bad UV map.
2. With <kbd>Shift</kbd> select one with good UV Map.
3. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> > **Transfer UV Map**.

[image: final]

Comment: Thank you, but still not working. Did what you suggested and still bad results, please watch the updated answer with attachments.

Comment: @Ermac Couple of things to note. Both meshes are not so identical. Look at te vertices count. Transfer UV is working fine but UV layout for second mesh is just bad. Removing Custom Normals doesn't help so there is something wrong with the mesh itself. Both have a lot, really lot Double Vertices. First one (decals) has some loose vertices even. Also calculating origin point to the center is nearly impossible to be the same on both. My advice here. Delete the one with custom normals and use Y.A.V.N.E add-on on the uv correct one.